# DOM manipulation in python/Django like Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I want do some DOM manipulation of my HTML file in Django/Python jut like JQuery
I want to select a p tag and change its value right inside python
Is there any library to manipulate html tags, set and get their values inside Python just like JQuery?

Please guide me to achieve this functionality. Please put some examples also

Comment: You can write a template `filter` for that purpose.

Comment: i want to change the text of p tag repeatedly and if i render the template again and again the i cause a lot of refresh of page so i want to avoid it as Jquery don't refresh the page so i need such functionality

Comment: I think you're looking for AJAX.

Comment: So do you render template, then manipulate DOM with jQuery and after then you want to send another rendered template that looks like one manipulated with jQuery? Is that why you need a python tool behaving like jQuery? If I missed with that guess, please extend your question with some context:)

Comment: Yes to explain it p tag is a status tag which display what's going on in the background as python is doing so much work in background so i want to display the status to user. Yes a i need a python tool which behaves like jquery not just refresh page on  render template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can look for more general libraries designed for 
[XML processing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml)